# How can i call a method from form1 to a new class without making the method in form1 static?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

And also without make a new instance ofr form1 in the new class.
In form1 i have a method i made it public:

```
public void Test()
{

}
```

Then this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{

    class SaveOldHtml
    {
        private static Form frm1 = null;
        private static int count;
        private static System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        private static string page;
        private static List<string> newText = new List<string>();

        public SaveOldHtml(string DirectoryToSave,int count, string contents)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(DirectoryToSave + "Page" + count.ToString("D6")
                                        + ".html", contents);
        }

        public SaveOldHtml(string DirectoryToSave, List<string> newTextList, int count)
        {
            using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(DirectoryToSave + "newTextList" + count.ToString("D6")
                                        + ".txt"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < newTextList.Count; i++)
                {
                    myStream.WriteLine(newTextList[i]);
                }

            }
        }

        public static void Start(Form1 form)
        {
            frm1 = form;
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Interval = 10000;
            count = 5;
            LoadOldHtmlFiles();
            _timer.Start();
        }
```

But frm1 dosen't have the property of the method from form1.
I need to make new instance in this class of form1 ? Or is there any other way without making instance and without making the method static ?

Comment: Why you don't want to create an instance of the form ? Is your form already open ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Anyway, I don't think it's a terrific idea to have public methods in Forms to be called by other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the parameter from the constructor as it's base type Form instead of it's actual type Form1.

Change

```
private static Form frm1 = null;
```

to

```
private static Form1 frm1 = null;
```

and frm1.Test() will be available.